# Parameter is hiding the type

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have an interface:

```
public interface Handler {
public <T> boolean shouldProcess(final T obj);
```

and implementation:

```
public class SampleHandler implements Handler {
@Override
public <Long> boolean shouldProcess(final Long date) {
 return <some comparison>;
}
```

I am getting "The type parameter Long is hiding the type Long".
What is the reason I am getting this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you're not instantiating `T` with the concrete type `Long`; you're actually declaring a new type variable called `Long` which has the same name as regular Longs and thus shadows them. I suspect you meant:

```
public interface Handler<T> {
  public boolean shouldProcess(final T obj);
}

public class SimpleHandler implements Handler<Long> {
  @Override
  public boolean shouldProcess(final Long date) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`<Long>` is a generic type parameter which happens to have the same name as the `java.lang.Long` class. Therefore it hides that class, so the `(final Long date)` argument of your method is of generic type and not of the `java.lang.Long` type.

If you want `SampleHandler` to implement `Handler` using `java.lang.Long` for the generic type parameter, I suggest you move the type parameter to the interface/class level:

```
public interface Handler<T> {
    public boolean shouldProcess(final T obj);
}

public class SampleHandler implements Handler<Long> {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldProcess(final Long date) {
        return <some comparison>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Long` or `java.lang.Long` is a built-in class.

Try not to use generic types, or custom classes, or variables which are the same name as common classes.

More likely you want to have a Handler which knows it's type, otherwise, it's much the same as using `Object`

```
public interface Handler<T> {
    public boolean shouldProcess(final T obj);

public class SampleHandler implements Handler<Long> {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldProcess(final Long date) {
        return <some comparison>;
    }
```